# How to design a new ble beacon protocol?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, design-principles

I am working in a project related to IoT where a gateway receive information form different sensors by mean of beacons.
One part of the project consist on design a new protocol which could be more generic, instead of needed to choose between iBeacons, Eddystone, etc.
The main purpose of this protocol would be to transmit data from sensor in a general way so it is compatible for several product in an efficient way.
Do you know where to find information, book, papers, etc about BLE beacon protocol design. Most of the information I found is about the beacon it self (the device), not the protocol.

Edit: The question is: **Where to find information about beacons protocol design?** Not needed comment about the idea itself.

Comment: See https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: Do no help... Current beacons are thought for smartphone interaction, and trigger events. Not for sensor data transmission.

Comment: "in a general way so it is compatible for several products in an efficient way" if you make a new protocol it won't be general and compatible with existing products. If you want to make a new custom protocol then it will be made only for your own use case and hence not general anymore (unless you hope to get it widespread). If you want to make it for yourself then you probably knows best which information you need to transmit.

Comment: Okay. I will simplify my question. Where to find information about beacon protocol design?

Comment: A beacon is just sending data via the BLE advertising packets.  If all you want to do is broadcast data via advertising packets then you can do that without investigating beacons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [AltBeacon project](https://altbeacon.org/) for an example of a BLE beacon protocol design.  The project shows the byte layout of the beacon format as well as the reason for its design.